# Is there any way to get an image from asp:Image Control(not from asp:FileUpload Control) in Asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, file-upload, asp.net-4.0

I am working with 1 asp.net image control and 1 asp:Fileupload control.

I use client-side scripts to open fileupload control and bind an image to image control. It's ok to get an image from server-side because I have chosen an image with server-side fileupload control so the image file is already in there.

But can I get the image file from imagecontrol? I am about to test drag and drop without fileupload control.

```
<style type="text/css">

    #upFile
    {
        opacity:0;
    }
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
        function performClick(node) {
            var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            evt.initEvent("click", true, false);
            node.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }

       function ImagePreview(Imagepath) {
        if (Imagepath.files && Imagepath.files[0]) {
            var Filerdr = new FileReader();
            Filerdr.onload = function (e) {
                $('#Image1').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            Filerdr.readAsDataURL(Imagepath.files[0]);
        }
    }
    </script>

<td>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1"  runat="server" Width="159px" Height="164px" 
            onClick="return performClick(document.getElementById('upFile'));"/>
</td>
<td>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="upFile" runat="server"  onchange="ImagePreview(this);"/>
</td>
```

Comment: You must upload the file to the server, then reference the the server path in your image control. You can't do this on the client side.

Comment: @RickS Thanks sir.i will try that way.